# Applying to another div other than the parent with jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I am trying to change the background color on the parent div wrapper for flexslider2 using jquery.adaptive-background.js

```
<section id="featured" class="dynamic-bg">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="flexslider effect7">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <div class="flexslider-item">
            <img src="images/slider/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" data-adaptive-background />
            <p class="flex-caption">Adventurer Cheesecake Brownie</p>
          </div>
        </li>
    <li>
      <div class="flexslider-item"><img src="images/slider/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" data-adaptive-background />
        <p class="flex-caption">Adventurer Lemon</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="flexslider-item"><img src="images/slider/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" data-adaptive-background />
        <p class="flex-caption">Adventurer Donut</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="flexslider-item"><img src="images/slider/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" data-adaptive-background />
        <p class="flex-caption">Adventurer Caramel</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Desired goal is for each slide image the section background to change color.

I have a pen up @ [Codepen by f1ss1on for dynamic BG of Flexslider](https://codepen.io/f1ss1on/pen/pwoGJL)

Comment: There is many way to do that, look at this page which explain how works your plugin. https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js/blob/master/README.md , in your case your parents is your section I think

Comment: @NathanMeunier actually the parents is the <li /> tag that wraps the image. I was able to get the section to grab just one background color but it did not change

Comment: Yeah sorry I mean in your case you have to put in the parent: the way to the section. I never used this script but, if I follow the instruction on the github it's should work. You have no error in the console ?

Comment: No. I dont have any errors. What it is doing is just grabbing one color and staying static that way. If I leave it default, the script on load grabs each image and puts the bg color on each parent flex-item.

Comment: I put up a pen [https://codepen.io/f1ss1on/pen/pwoGJL](https://codepen.io/f1ss1on/pen/pwoGJL)